# Typescript Nested Promises Return Type Mismatch

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using typescript 2.2.1

Code with compile error:

```
createNewUser(name): Promise<UserModel> {
    return this.getRef().then(Ref => {  //getRef() return Promise<number>
        let newUser: UserModel = {
            displayName: name,
            ref: Ref
        };

        return this.database.insert(newUser).then(() => {  //database.insert() return Promise<void>
            return newUser;
        });
    });
}
```

This is the error from the compiler:

> Type 'Promise< number>' is not assignable to type 'Promise< UserModel>'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'UserModel'.

Code WITHOUT compile error:

```
createNewUser(name): Promise<any> {
    return this.getRef().then(Ref => {
        let newUser: UserModel = {
            displayName: name,
            ref: Ref
        };

        return this.database.insert(newUser).then(() => {
            return newUser;
        });
    });
}
```

Notice that to fix this, I only change the return type for this method.
This code run well during runtime too.

For clarification:

```
createNewUser('test').then(result=>{
    console.log(result);    //result = { displayName: 'test', ref: 999 }
});
```

Now my question is, is this a bug in typescript? 
The compiler actually mistaken the return type of the nested Promise.

Comment: when you resolve this promise like createNewUser().then(data => { console.log(data); }) using also the any type, is a number printed? or your object?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this method returns a Promise<number> where the number is the result of the insert operation

Comment: you guys can try it, it actually return the newUser object. Because thats how promise chaining works. The "then" actually create a new promise and return it. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Nope, I think the issue here is only with declarations. 
if the insert method returns a Promise<number> as type, when inside your method you return this.database.insert(newUser), actually the method is expecting for a Promise<number> to be returned. Did you get what I mean?

Comment: try it wrapping your last code with a new promise like return new Promise<UserModel> ((resolve, reject) => {
 return this.database.insert(newUser).then(() => {
            resolve();
            return newUser;
        });
});
and see if you still have your error
p.s. if you don't have implicit any as option, wrap all with any just for testing now

Comment: @quirimmo FYI, the insert() is returning Promise<void>, from here we can clearly see that the compiler check against the return type of getRef() not insert(). Which is super weird.

Comment: yeah sorry haven't seen that return getRef at the beginning. I think it makes sense that the main return has been checked against the first return statement of the body. Can you try to wrap all the body in a new Promise<UserModel> returned? if you get rid of the issue, this is what is happening

Comment: @quirimmo I did though of wrapping it all in a new Promise, but after experiment with this method. I found that the error in the promises will not be catch without explicitly .catch and the level getRef() and insert(). The code become less elegant. But the point is, why is Typescript complaining the code base on a wrong assumption? Is it a bug?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144789/discussion-between-terrence-and-quirimmo).

Comment: Updating to Typescript 2.3 should fix this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13008

Comment: @Gerrit0 Looks like that is the answer I'm looking for. Thanks. I will try it tonight. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Solution**

Update to Typescript 2.3 or above

---

As per what @Gerrit suggested, update to Typescript 2.3 will resolve this issue. I have tested it, and it works. Thanks @Gerrit

This issue has been discussed in the [Typescript github](http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13008)